# Add a variable to a struct at runtime C++

Tags: c++

I have a struct:

```
struct MyStruct{
}
```

I want to be able to add a pointer to a variable at runtime

```
std::string myString = "Hello";
MyStruct my_struct;
```

As an example if there was a function that did this it would be like this

```
std::add_to_struct(&my_struct, &myString);
```

and you can retrieve that variable using:

```
std::get_struct_variable<std::string>("myString");
```

Comment: Does `std::map` do what you want? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Never expand `std` namespace

Comment: @FridayPie  what do you mean by that?

Comment: Swift-FridayPie is talking about `std::add_to_struct` and `std::get_struct_variable` which are not existent in namespace `std`. That namespace is reserved. Adding stuff inside is UB. (some specialization are allowed though).

Comment: @Jarod42 "expanding" the std namespace does seem to be possible though? I tried it

Comment: @caelras: It is UB, And one possible output of UB is seems to works. Remember that, in practice, standard might add stuff in `std` in future version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding fields to structs or classes at runtime isn't allowed, by design. More dynamic languages like JavaScript support this because the runtime "knows" which fields each object has, and what their names are. In C++ (ignoring debug info), this info is only known at compile time. At runtime, an instance of `MyStruct` is just a piece of memory of length `sizeof(MyStruct)`. There is no room to add additional fields. Even if `MyStruct` instances could be made longer, any code complied to handle a `MyStruct` wouldn't know how to interpret the additional bytes, because that info wasn't available at compile time.

If you want a dictionary-like object that can associate arbitrary string names with values, use `std::map` like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string,int> dict;
  dict["hello"] = 100;
  dict["good bye"] = 200;
  std::cout << dict["hello"] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In this example, the values are `int`s. If you need values of different types in the same data structure, there are a few options. You could change the values from `int` to `void*`:

```
int main() {
  std::map<std::string,void*> dict;
  dict["hello"] = new int(100);
  std::cout << *static_cast<int*>(dict["hello"]) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Instead of storing the values directly in the `map`, we instead create values of any type on the heap, and only store their pointers in the `map`. This simple, but error-prone, and I don't recommend it. `void*` circumvents C++'s type safety by making all types interchangeable. Notice that when we retrieve our data from `dict`, the retrieving code has to know to cast the pointer back to `int`. If you cast back to the wrong type, you'll get garbage data.

Also notice that this program leaks memory! You could be diligent about individually freeing each item from each `map` when you're done with it, or you could used `std::unique_ptr` to do that automatically. But in either case you're going to find that the code which frees the elements needs to know what type each element is, and how to properly free that particular type. What if one of your types contains pointers to yet more objects that must be freed first?

You could alternatively make the values unions:

```
typedef union {
  int i;
  char c;
} IntChar;

int main() {
  std::map<std::string,IntChar> dict;
  IntChar ic;
  ic.i = 100;
  dict["hello"] = ic;
  std::cout << dict["hello"].i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This restores some partial type-safety, since you can only interpret the data as one of the types pre-defined in the union. But it has the drawbacks that you must pre-define all possible types in the union, there are limits on what types you can put in a union, and each instance of the union will be sized to accommodate the largest type inside it, which may waste memory if most of your instances use the smaller types.

Union's limitations may be acceptable to you. If not, then the most type-safe and extensible solution, at the expense of more code, is to make `map` values pointers to a base class type, and then create derived classes for each type you want to put in the dictionary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};

class DerivedInt : public Base {
public:
  int i;
  DerivedInt(int i_) : i(i_) {}
  std::string to_string() override { return std::to_string(i); }
};

class DerivedChar : public Base { 
public:
  char c;
  DerivedChar(int c_) : c(c_) {}
  std::string to_string() override { return std::string(&c, 1); }
};

int main() {
  std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<Base>> dict;
  dict["hello"] = std::make_unique<DerivedInt>(100);
  dict["good bye"] = std::make_unique<DerivedChar>('z');
  std::cout << dict["hello"]->to_string() << std::endl;
  std::cout << dict["good bye"]->to_string() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This way, each derived class is responsible for its own particular fields, and the calling code need not worry about their differences. If any derived type needs to be freed in a particular way, it can implement its own destructor to do so.

This is all assuming, of course, that your use-case actually needs to associate arbitrary names with arbitrary data. If you're just trying to port a scripting language coding style over to C++ by using dictionaries instead of classes and structs, I'd recommend instead that you embrace the strengths and limitations of C++ while working in C++. That means deciding ahead of time what classes and fields you need, and declaring them up front so the compiler can help spot your mistakes.

Comment: [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) instead of `void*` and [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of `union`.